# Terminologies: Generative models for discrete data

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, supervised-learning

I am reading Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective. The title of chapter 3 is 'Generative Models for Discrete Data'. The introduction is short, but I do not understand why the word 'generative' is used. What is being generated? (And as opposed to what other forms of models?)

Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

Simply looking at [generative models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_model#Generative_models) on Wikipedia, I read that in machine learning, the generative approach is opposed to the discriminative approach. The *generative model* corresponds to the conditional density $p(x|Y=y)$ of the data given the model index, while the *discriminative* model is the conditional probability $\Bbb P(Y=y|X=x)$ of the index given the observation. The later usually avoids modeling the observable. Generative and discriminative models are also used simultaneously in [Generative Adversarial Networks](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets.pdf) (GANs).